# Why is webhook which has been successfully created by the app not showing up in the Shopify admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify

I am creating a demo plugin for Shopify and getting issues with creating Webhooks for the admin. I am doing something as below.

```
pry(#<HomeController>)> webhook = ShopifyAPI::Webhook.create(:format => "json", :topic => "carts/create", :address => "http://requestb.in/1k49wje1/")

=> #<ShopifyAPI::Webhook:0x007fe8207141d8
 @attributes=
 {"format"=>"json",
   "topic"=>"carts/create",
   "address"=>"http://requestb.in/1k49wje1/",
   "id"=>6726111,
   "created_at"=>"2014-08-12T08:33:42-04:00",
   "fields"=>[],
   "metafield_namespaces"=>[],
   "updated_at"=>"2014-08-12T08:33:42-04:00"},
 @errors=#<ActiveResource::Errors:0x007fe82071f0d8 @base=# 

<ShopifyAPI::Webhook:0x007fe8207141d8 ...>, @messages={}>,
 @persisted=true,
 @prefix_options={},
 @remote_errors=nil,
 @validation_context=nil>


pry(#<HomeController>)> ShopifyAPI::Webhook.all.count
=> 1
```

If I create another webhook for the same topic, it throws an error. Why is the webhook not showing up in my shopify admin? What am I missing here?

EDIT: I tried running the same code on my friend's system and he could access my webhook using `count`  and when he created, I also could access the webhook. What is happening here? Webhooks are being created on two different systems but not showing up in admin section? If not on admin, where are they getting persisted?

Comment: have you created the routes to post them correctly?

Comment: how do I post them? Please see the edits for the question also. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webhooks never show up in the Admin. For good reason. You created them with the API for a reason. If they showed up in the Admin, anyone with access to the Admin could just delete them, completely screwing up your App. So you just read webhooks using the API and your key and then determine if they are there or not.. pretty neat eh?